# Is it possible that ridge logistic regression will also reduce coefficients to exactly zero?

Tags: machine-learning, references, ridge-regression

I have 105 predictors which contain dummy, numerical, and nominal variables. The output variable is dichotomous. I ran ridge logistic regression in R, using the following syntax:

```
glmnet(x, y, alpha=0, family="binomial")
```

After this I plotted the model. It shows that the variables are not all included in the model. Instead of 105, now there are only 72 variables (including the intercept). But why are the coefficients going to zero?

I need some literature to prove it. Any literature that explains that ridge will also reduce coefficients exactly to zero will be helpful.

Comment: How much data do you have? In particular, how many positive & negative cases are there?

Answer (score 0):

You will see the coefficient paths will converge to zero (with increasing lambda), regardless of the regularisation being L1 or L2 or a mixture (elastic net). The difference is Lasso makes shrinking much faster compared to Ridge. It is quite simple to demonstrate.

```
# Load libraries
if(!require("glmnet")) { install.packages("glmnet");  require("glmnet") }

x=matrix(rnorm(100*20),100,20)
y=rnorm(100)
g2=sample(1:2,100,replace=TRUE)
g4=sample(1:4,100,replace=TRUE)
# Ridge
fit11 = glmnet(x,y, alpha=0)
# Elastic Net
fit12 = glmnet(x,y, alpha=0.5)
# Lasso
fit13 = glmnet(x,y, alpha=1)

par(mfrow=c(3,1))
plot(fit11,xvar="lambda", xlim=c(-7,5))
plot(fit12,xvar="lambda", xlim=c(-7,5))
plot(fit13,xvar="lambda", xlim=c(-7,5))
```

Comment: Please do not include `rm(list=ls())` in code you post here! Some users could get angry at you after running it ... I removed it for now.